# g++ linker segment

Tags: linker, g++

Is it possible to specify what linker segment that a piece of code in a c++ source file will reside in? For example,

int foo() { ... }    --->   place in Link Segment A

int bar() { ... }    --->   place in Link Segment B

I vaguely recall some source code like the following

**codea_** int foo () { ... }

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gcc you can use the `__attribute__((section))` syntax to specify the linker section for a symbol. (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_4.html#SEC84) for details)

You should be able to use the same syntax in g++